# Using S3 as a sink (StreamingFileSink)

Tags: apache-flink

We are using Flink to process input events and aggregate and write o/p of our streaming job to S3 using StreamingFileSink but whenever we try to restore the job from a savepoint, the restoration fails with missing part files error. As per my understanding, s3 deletes those part(intermittent) files and can no longer be found on s3. Is there a workaround for this, so that we can use s3 as a sink?

Comment: Where a savepoint is saved is not related to any sink your workflow is using, thus I doubt there's any connection between using S3 as a sink and a failure to restore from a savepoint. How did you configure your savepoint directory? See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/savepoints.html#configuration

Comment: did you solve this? We have the same issue with using S3 as the sink and the store for the savepoints. The temp files are deleted so the job fails on restore with `No such file or directory` when trying to restore the temp files.

Comment: Looks to have been addressed here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-13940